# Member variable pointer to self in C++

Tags: c++, static-members

When I try to compile this code, why does g++ report an error?

```
class A {
  private:
    static A* Aptr[5];
  public:
    static int A_count;
    A() {
        Aptr[A_count] = this;
    }
};

int A::A_count = 0;

int main() {
    A a_;
    A b_;
    return 0;
}
```

```
/tmp/ccrp4BGg.o: In function `A::A()':
try.cpp:(.text._ZN1AC2Ev[_ZN1AC5Ev]+0x18): undefined reference to `A::Aptr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You might need to define it, similar to how you define `A_count`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: specifically the definition should be `A *A::Aptr[5];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Explanation

You have only **declared** your *static data-member* named `A::Aptr`, but in order to use it, as you are inside the constructor of `A`, you must provide a **definition**.

The linker diagnostic might say *undefined reference*, which might be hard to relate to a missing definition, but it's talking about its internal mapping of names and storage location.

In other words; the linker is unable to find a a *reference* (ie. entry) for the location where `A::Aptr` is stored, which makes sense: Without a definition you haven't given `A::APtr` any storage to use.

---

#### Solution

You've already provided both a **declaration** *(2)*, and a **definition** *(4)* for `A::A_count`, if you do the same for `A::APtr` you will be all set.

```
class A {
 private:
    static A* Aptr[5];   // (1), declaration
 public:
    static int A_count;  // (2), declaration
    A() {
        Aptr[A_count] = this;
    }
};

A*  A::APtr[5];     // (3), definition  <-- previously missing! 
int A::A_count = 0; // (4), definition
```

---

<sup>**Note**: You are only asking about the linker error, but I'm guessing you mean to increment `A_count` upon constructing an object of type `A`, something which you are currently **not** doing.</sup>

Comment: @user1135541 Glad to be of service. To flag the problem as being solved, consider marking the answer as *Accepted*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define it outside the class, just like any other static variable:

Answer (score 0):

Because it is static you need to define `Aptr` outside of the class, right now you have only declared it but not defined and initialized it. This means that the linker can't find it. Also do you want to increment `A_count`?:

```
class A {
 private:
    static A* Aptr[5];
 public:
    static int A_count;
    A() {
        Aptr[A_count] = this;
        A_count++; //I presume you want to do something like this too
    }
};

int A::A_count = 0;
A* A::Aptr[5] = { nullptr }

int main() {
    A a_;
    A b_;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: The initializers are redundant, as static data is always value-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
  private:
    static A* Aptr[5];
  public:
    static int A_count;
    A() {
        Aptr[A_count] = this;
    }
    //static ctor
    static A(){
         Aptr=new A[5];
         A_count=0;
    }
};


int main() {
    A a_;
    A b_;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point, this time I am working on embedded system with no heap, but this looks like a cleaner solution if there is not already a source file.  Hate create source files for just one line.